# Best way to protect chart data

Tags: javascript, css

In my website i need to put a chart with data, like: http://www.swapmeetdave.com/Bible/StockGraph.gif

I need the chart to be sexy. To archive this I have to use CSS+JS. But I don't weant anyone to be able to scrap the chart data.

If I use an image chart, I protect the data but the filesize is too big.

1) Is there a way to create a non image chart and make sure no one will be able to extract the information?

2) Is there a way to create an ultra low size image with only a signle color (green line in the chart above)? png is 4-6kb. Can I do this with < 1kb? SVG maybe?

Comment: You mean you don't want people to see the actual data used to make the graph? In that case I don't think you should go with SVG, because then you would have the data in the source. By the way, if I save your example chart as monochrome PNG, it's only 1304 bytes.

Comment: Yes, I don't want anyone to **easily** copy the chart data. This is just an example, my chart is bigger.

Comment: I know if someone wants, can copy everything, even extract the data from an image. But I don't want to make that job easy.

Comment: Maybe you can do something with Flash. Although I'm not familiar with Flash programming, and I don't know how easy that would be to reverse engineer.

Comment: Thnaks for the reply. Flash is not an option as I need the site to work on all browsers... Mobile devices dosen't support flash.

Comment: Define "create". You could use something such as Adobe Illustrator or Microsoft Chart tools to create the chart and save it as a png. This, of course, would not be live data on the web. If you want ever-changing live data, I'd use a PHP script to generate an image from chart data. I don't think javascript and CSS will do it since they are both client-side.

Comment: You are corrent here, this is what i might do. I am thinking of using this: http://psydk.org/PngOptimizer.php

Comment: By "create" i mean, i need to have dynamicly generated charts on the site. They will change, say about once a day.

Comment: A PNG Optimizer is not going to create the actual chart image.

Comment: Yes, if I use one I am planning to make the actual image using php and then optimize it. The drawback is the cpu power needed...